# Airflow SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: email, airflow

Using Airflow 2.0.1 with the following `airflow.cfg` configuration. I am trying to send an email notification. My gmail account 2-factor-authentication activated.

```
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = False
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = <my_gmail_user@gmail.com>
smtp_password = <my_password>
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = <my_gmail_user@gmail.com>
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_retry_limit = 5
```

My e-mail task

```
send_email_notification = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email_notification',
        to='<my_another_working_email>@hotmail.com',
        subject='Airflow mail test',
        html_content="<h3> Airflow mail test</h2>"
    )
```

But I got the following error. During the airflow installation, I specified `admin@vbo.local` as admin user mail which actually doesn't exist. I am not sure it is the reason for the error.

```
ERROR - SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1112, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 87, in execute
    mime_charset=self.mime_charset,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 62, in send_email
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 97, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=smtp_mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 195, in send_mime_email
    conn.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 697, in login
    "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
[2021-05-20 16:04:49,885] {taskinstance.py:1503} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=my_data_pipeline, task_id=send_email_notification, execution_date=20210520T125758, start_date=20210520T130449, end_date=20210520T130449
[2021-05-20 16:04:49,914] {email.py:184} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2021-05-20 16:04:50,227] {email.py:184} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2021-05-20 16:04:50,484] {taskinstance.py:1509} ERROR - Failed to send email to: admin@vbo.local
[2021-05-20 16:04:50,484] {taskinstance.py:1510} ERROR - SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1112, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 87, in execute
    mime_charset=self.mime_charset,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 62, in send_email
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 97, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=smtp_mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 195, in send_mime_email
    conn.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 697, in login
    "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1852, in email_alert
    send_email(self.task.email, subject, html_content)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 62, in send_email
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 97, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=smtp_mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 195, in send_mime_email
    conn.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 697, in login
    "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1507, in handle_failure
    self.email_alert(error)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1854, in email_alert
    send_email(self.task.email, subject, html_content_err)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 62, in send_email
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 97, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=smtp_mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/train/venvairflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 195, in send_mime_email
    conn.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 697, in login
    "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
[2021-05-20 16:04:50,538] {local_task_job.py:146} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the smtp config to `smtp_starttls = True`
All major email clients use a secure connection. A bit about StartTLS, its a protocol command used to inform the email server that the email client wants to upgrade from an insecure connection to a secure one using TLS or SSL.